# Where can I read the Kiteretsu Daihyakka manga free online in English?

Tags: kiteretsu-daihyakka

I would like to read the complete Kiteretsu Daihyakka manga free online in English. Can anyone provide me a link for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some Googling, it appears that there is no *licensed* translation of the manga (and thus, no way to legally read it for free online). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiteretsu_Daihyakka) does not list any English publisher for *Kiteretsu Daihyakka*; in contrast, it does for *Doraemon* (of which I've personally read licensed translations of certain chapters) or any number of other licensed manga.

I was also unable to find any promising results when I Googled `kiteretsu daihyakka manga english translation`.